# lightdm autologin on openSUSE

Tags: linux, opensuse

How create lightdm auto login for user "test" on openSUSE
This code not working for me:

```
printf '[SeatDefaults]\nautologin-user=test\nautologin-user-timeout=0' > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

it load to normal login screen.

Answer (score -1):

use yast2 or edit `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager` and set `DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN` to **"user"**

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
## Path:    Desktop/Display manager
## Description: settings to generate a proper displaymanager config
DISPLAYMANAGER="lightdm"

## Type:    string
## Default:
DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="user"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
DISPLAYMANAGER_PASSWORD_LESS_LOGIN="yes"
```

Comment: It rather seems to be
```DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="user"``` and ```DISPLAYMANAGER_PASSWORD_LESS_LOGIN="yes"```. You may want to ```passwd -d user``` and make sure the user's home exists and has the correct permissions.

Comment: they are typos, the base was correct. And Anybody can fix this instead of complaining.